# login in problem with correct password

Tags: login, password

I cannot login in Ubuntu 16.04 although correct password is entered. The password works when using in <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>.

I searched online similar problems and tried, but it didn't work out.

genome-desktop, unity, ... are removed. cinnamon is installed right now.

However it still has problem.

There is no graphic card in my laptop.

Please help me.

Comment: Does the screen seem like it will log in, then bring you back to the login loop?

Comment: yes. it is like that. now I installed others desktop environments (lxde, lubuntu, openbox, and reinstalled ubuntu desktop), but still cannot enter.

Comment: and tried xsession-error but no idea what should I find.

Comment: Try going to the ctrl alt f1 terminal, login, and then type cd~  then press enter, then type sudo chown username:groupname .Xauthority press enter, then type mv .Xauthority Xauthority.bak

Comment: it also didn't work. finally I typed 'startx' and then opens new administrator acc and then deleted the old acc. new acc works.

Comment: So it works now?